# How to convert number to Julian date in r?

Tags: r

```
day <- c(seq(1, 10592, by = 1))
```

How to change 'day' into Julian date format from 1st January 1982 to 31st December 2010).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this what you want? `day = seq(as.Date("1982-01-01"), as.Date("2010-12-31"), by = "day")`

Comment: have a look at `?as.Date`

Comment: ...and `seq.Date`, which is suggested on `?seq`. Well, basically _do some research_ before you post your question. And show what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks a lot @shujaa and Ricardo Saporta. That is exactly what I need. Actually my dataset consist of two columns. The first column appear as number 1 to 10592. The second column is the rainfall values. Just wondering if r could convert the first column into Julian date without having to produce another new column.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `help.search("Julian")` -- there is a function `julian`.

So given your date sequence (and replace the `length=...` with `by="1 day"` for all dates)

```
R> seq(as.Date("1982-01-01"), as.Date("2010-12-31"), length=5)
[1] "1982-01-01" "1989-04-01" "1996-07-01" "2003-10-01" "2010-12-31"
R>
```

you compute Julian dates just by calling the function:

```
R> julian(seq(as.Date("1982-01-01"), as.Date("2010-12-31"), length=5))
[1]  4383.00  7030.75  9678.50 12326.25 14974.00
attr(,"origin")
[1] "1970-01-01"
R>
```