# R convert date into Julian day

Tags: r, julian-date

I want to convert dates into Julian day

```
x <- c('5/5/2007')
# convert to day of year (Julian date) 

strptime(x, "%m/%d/%Y")$yday+1 
#125
```

There are two things I do not understand in this:

1) What is `y$day + 1` doing?

When I run it for more dates, it gives me NA for some dates.

```
date<-c("09/06/1997","01/06/1998","26/05/1999","02/06/2000","01/06/2001","06/06/2002","05/06/2003",
    "21/05/2004","16/06/2005","27/05/2006","08/06/2007","09/06/1997","01/06/1998")

strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")$yday+1 
[1] 249   6  NA  37   6 157 126  NA  NA  NA 218 249   6
```

I am not sure why is this happening? And why do we need `$yday+1`

Comment: The first is incrementing by one day (+1). You are getting NAs because you have a typo in your format. It should be : "%d/%m/%Y".

Comment: Some of the dates in your vector are in the format `%d/%m/%Y`, and hence the NAs in your result

Comment: For more about Julian days: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080241/how-to-convert-number-to-julian-date-in-r
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414847/convert-a-date-vector-into-julian-day-in-r

Comment: Thanks. I understand this now.

Comment: I'd recommend to either move the comments that answered the question into an answer or to remove the question