# Converting sets of calendar dates to Julian days in a data frame

Tags: r, date, dataframe, calendar, julian-date

I am a beginner in R and I am trying to convert sets of calendar dates to sets of Julian dates in a data frame using R. I know there are a similar questions answered but I am not being able to get I want.

```
df <- data.frame(Date = c('2010-06-20','2005-10-19','2000-05-01','2003-04-04','2010-11-20','2009-09-14'), No = c(1, 4, 6, 11, 7, 9))

df$ jDate <-  as.POSIXct(as.numeric(df$Date), origin = '1970-01-01')
```

gives me

> df
>
> Date No               cDate
>
> 1 2010-06-20  1 1969-12-31 19:00:05
>
> 2 2005-10-19  4 1969-12-31 19:00:03
>
> 3 2000-05-01  6 1969-12-31 19:00:01
>
> 4 2003-04-04 11 1969-12-31 19:00:02
>
> 5 2010-11-20  7 1969-12-31 19:00:06
>
> 6 2009-09-14  9 1969-12-31 19:00:04

How could I get a column with Julian days in the column 'jDate'?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You may find the `julian` function useful.

Comment: I tried tojulian and julian at some point when I was trying to figure this out but this time it actually worked! Thank you for bringing it up!

Comment: I highly appreciate it if anybody can tell me how to properly post the output...

Comment: Related post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080241/how-to-convert-number-to-julian-date-in-r

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)
```

to get the date, and then

```
df$jDate <- format(df$Date, "%j")
```

to get the julian days or

```
df$jDateYr <- format(df$Date, "%Y-%j")
```

to prepend the year (if you want). This returns

```
df
        Date No jDate  jDateYr
1 2010-06-20  1   171 2010-171
2 2005-10-19  4   292 2005-292
3 2000-05-01  6   122 2000-122
4 2003-04-04 11   094 2003-094
5 2010-11-20  7   324 2010-324
6 2009-09-14  9   257 2009-257
```

To read more about the possible date-time formats, see `?strptime`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I am trying to obtain Julian days since 1970-01-01 so that days between different years can be calculated (i.e. needs to be not bounded by 0 to 365). Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Based on aosmith's comments, I did this and got what I wanted.

```
> df$jDate <- julian(as.Date(df$Date), origin = as.Date('1970-01-01'))
```

> df
>
> Date No jDate
>
> 1 2010-06-20  1 14780
>
> 2 2005-10-19  4 13075
>
> 3 2000-05-01  6 11078
>
> 4 2003-04-04 11 12146
>
> 5 2010-11-20  7 14933
>
> 6 2009-09-14  9 14501